# Can reads from an MD RAID 1 be inconcsistent?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, raid, mdadm, raid1

While a RAID 1 gives the benefit of redundancy I'm trying to understand whether using a RAID can lead to inconsistencies under any circumstances (I/O errors, not disk, ...).

In an effort to understand this I read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/4/md), which left me with some questions.

> Changes are written to all devices in parallel.

(1) Is the write only confirmed back to the system after all writes to all disks completed (except disks marked as faulty)?

> For RAID1, this [making the array consistent after unclean shutdown] involves copying the contents of the first drive onto all other drives.

(2) The first device may or may not contain the most recent write. So it potentially overwrites data on the second disk that is newer. As long as the answer to (1) is yes, this shouldn't be a problem, right?

> If the md driver detects a write error [...], it immediately disables that device (marking it as faulty) and continues operation on the remaining devices.

(3) Is this information persisted (e.g. across reboots) before write operations continue?

(4) Is the write-intent log just an optimization or does it help it certain scenarios where data loss is otherwise unavoidable?

Consider the following scenario:

1. md0 RAID 1 with devices sda and sdb
2. `abc` is written to md0
3. sdb fails and is marked as faulty
4. `xyz` is written to md0 (effectively sda now)
5. The system reboots and afterwards only sdb is available (for whatever reason)
6. What happens when I read from md0? What content will I read?

Essentially, I want to understand whether using a RAID 1 (md in particular) can cause writes that have been confirmed back to the user to be lost (potentially unnoticed) where a single disk would simply fail to write (availability vs consistency).

Comment: In the described scenario where a failed disc comes back to life *and* a good disc becomes unavailable I guess you would lose writes that have been confirmed, as there is really nowhere (accessible) that it could have been noted that writes happened while sdb was out. But in scenarios where you have discs that are coming and going I think it will be hard to achieve better.

Comment: it's possible to construct such a situation where it happens, yes. some distros refuse to boot / run off a degraded raid and request admin to intervene and hope they know their stuff, for similar such reasons.

Comment: *What happens when I read from md0? What content will I read?* - Nothing, you've got no RAID. `sdb` is faulty, it will not be initialized.

Comment: if sdb just up and vanishes... you can't mark anything faulty on it, because its gone. if it then comes back after a reboot as the only drive, it will look like any other power loss event. it will run (degraded) and give you old data.

Comment: Can you get IO errors from RAID. Consider the following thought experiment: Smash all hard disks with a fire axe. Will the system continue to work, or will you get IO errors?